# I can't figure out how to write a function inside a class using Dictionary. Thanks

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
class Car {
    
    let color: String
    let model: String
    var doors: [Int:String] = [:]
    let brand: String
    let state: String
    
    init (color: String, model: String, doors: [Int:String], brand: String, state: String) {
        self.color = color
        self.model = model
        self.doors = doors
        self.brand = brand
        self.state = state
    }
    
    
    func openDoor (numberDoor: Int) {
        
    }
    
    func closeDoor (numberDoor: Int) {
        
    }
    
    
    
}

let car = Car(color: "Black", model: "A8", doors: [1:"Door #1", 2: "Door #2"], brand: "Audi", state: "Stop")
```

I enter the door number and it displays a message on the console that "the door is open", if I enter it again with the same number - the message that "the door is ALREADY open". Door numbers are recorded in the Dictionary.

**Example**
car.openDoor(number: 2) // "Door 2 is opened"
car.openDoor(number: 2) // "Door 2 IS ALREADY OPENED

Comment: To increase your chance of getting some help you should include your attempt at solving the problem and explaining in better detail why and you are stuck and can't solve the problem. You should also be clear about this being homework with some specific requirements or if it's your own code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var alreadyOpen: [Int] = []

func openDoor (numberDoor: Int) {

    if alreadyOpen.contains(numberDoor) {
        print("door is already opend")
    } else {
        print("door is open")

      alreadyOpen.append(numberDoor)
    }
}
```

> create a var with name "alreadyOpen"

```
var alreadyOpen: [Int] = []
```

> below Condition menning if this number is available in **[alreadyOpen]** array so **print("door is already opend")** else **print("door is open")** and add a element in array.

```
if alreadyOpen.contains(numberDoor)
```